# How to include purecss to my application when using rails-assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I use this gem: `gem 'rails-assets-purecss', '~> 0.6.0'` to fetch the purecss library.

Now how can I include it into my project? `*= require purecss` and `*= require_tree purecss` both throw errors.

I understand that this library has many folders inside of it with each containing seperate files. But should the `require_tree` not be the tool for this kind of job then?

Errors:

```
Sprockets::FileNotFound - couldn't find file 'purecss' with type 'text/css':
  app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss:3:in `'
  sprockets (3.1.0) lib/sprockets/resolve.rb:64:in `resolve!'
  sprockets (3.1.0) lib/sprockets/directive_processor.rb:399:in `resolve'
  sprockets (3.1.0) lib/sprockets/directive_processor.rb:207:in `process_require_directive'
  sprockets (3.1.0) lib/sprockets/directive_processor.rb:180:in `block in process_directives'
  sprockets (3.1.0) lib/sprockets/directive_processor.rb:178:in `each'
  sprockets (3.1.0) lib/sprockets/directive_processor.rb:178:in `process_directives'
  sprockets (3.1.0) lib/sprockets/directive_processor.rb:83:in `_call'
  sprockets (3.1.0) lib/sprockets/directive_processor.rb:68:in `call'
  sprockets (3.1.0) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:75:in `call_processor'
  sprockets (3.1.0) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:57:in `block in call_processors'
  sprockets (3.1.0) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `reverse_each'
  sprockets (3.1.0) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `call_processors'
  sprockets (3.1.0) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:86:in `load_asset_by_uri'
  sprockets (3.1.0) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:45:in `block in load'
  sprockets (3.1.0) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:156:in `fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'
  sprockets (3.1.0) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:38:in `load'
  sprockets (3.1.0) lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:20:in `block in initialize'
  sprockets (3.1.0) lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `yield'
  sprockets (3.1.0) lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `load'
  sprockets (3.1.0) lib/sprockets/bundle.rb:23:in `block in call'
  sprockets (3.1.0) lib/sprockets/utils.rb:183:in `dfs'
  sprockets (3.1.0) lib/sprockets/bundle.rb:24:in `call'
  sprockets (3.1.0) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:75:in `call_processor'
  sprockets (3.1.0) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:57:in `block in call_processors'
  sprockets (3.1.0) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `reverse_each'
  sprockets (3.1.0) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `call_processors'
  sprockets (3.1.0) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:86:in `load_asset_by_uri'
  sprockets (3.1.0) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:45:in `block in load'
  sprockets (3.1.0) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:156:in `fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'
  sprockets (3.1.0) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:38:in `load'
  sprockets (3.1.0) lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:20:in `block in initialize'
  sprockets (3.1.0) lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `yield'
  sprockets (3.1.0) lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `load'
  sprockets (3.1.0) lib/sprockets/base.rb:63:in `find_asset'
  sprockets (3.1.0) lib/sprockets/environment.rb:30:in `find_asset'
  sprockets (3.1.0) lib/sprockets/base.rb:89:in `[]'
  sprockets-rails (2.3.1) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:243:in `lookup_asset_for_path'
  sprockets-rails (2.3.1) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:203:in `check_errors_for'
  sprockets-rails (2.3.1) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:172:in `block in stylesheet_link_tag'
  sprockets-rails (2.3.1) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:171:in `map'
  sprockets-rails (2.3.1) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:171:in `stylesheet_link_tag'
  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:9:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___2778102101062006255_69903052436420'
  actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
  actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/template.rb:333:in `instrument'
  actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
  actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:66:in `render_with_layout'
  actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:52:in `render_template'
  actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:14:in `render'
  actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:42:in `render_template'
  actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:23:in `render'
  actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:100:in `_render_template'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:217:in `_render_template'
  actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:83:in `render_to_body'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:32:in `render_to_body'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:37:in `render_to_body'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:25:in `render'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in `block (2 levels) in render'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `block in ms'
  /home/kaspar/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/benchmark.rb:303:in `realtime'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `ms'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in `block in render'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:84:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
  activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:25:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `render'
  app/controllers/application_controller.rb:35:in `intercept_html_requests'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:427:in `block in make_lambda'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:163:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:163:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:151:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:151:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:234:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:234:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `_run_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:734:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
  activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:137:in `process'
  actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:236:in `block in action'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:42:in `serve'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `each'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:802:in `call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
  rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in `call'
  rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
  rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in `call'
  rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
  rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:647:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/migration.rb:378:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `_run_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:734:in `_run_call_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
  better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:84:in `protected_app_call'
  better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:79:in `better_errors_call'
  better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:57:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  quiet_assets (1.1.0) lib/quiet_assets.rb:27:in `call_with_quiet_assets'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
  rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:113:in `call'
  rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
  railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
  railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/application.rb:164:in `call'
  passenger (5.0.7) lib/phusion_passenger/rack/thread_handler_extension.rb:89:in `process_request'
  passenger (5.0.7) lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:155:in `accept_and_process_next_request'
  passenger (5.0.7) lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:110:in `main_loop'
  passenger (5.0.7) lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler.rb:414:in `block (3 levels) in start_threads'
  passenger (5.0.7) lib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb:111:in `block in create_thread_and_abort_on_exception'


Sprockets::ArgumentError - require_tree argument must be a relative path:
  app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss:3:in `'
  sprockets (3.1.0) lib/sprockets/directive_processor.rb:383:in `expand_relative_dirname'
  sprockets (3.1.0) lib/sprockets/directive_processor.rb:244:in `process_require_tree_directive'
  sprockets (3.1.0) lib/sprockets/directive_processor.rb:180:in `block in process_directives'
  sprockets (3.1.0) lib/sprockets/directive_processor.rb:178:in `each'
  sprockets (3.1.0) lib/sprockets/directive_processor.rb:178:in `process_directives'
  sprockets (3.1.0) lib/sprockets/directive_processor.rb:83:in `_call'
  sprockets (3.1.0) lib/sprockets/directive_processor.rb:68:in `call'
  sprockets (3.1.0) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:75:in `call_processor'
  sprockets (3.1.0) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:57:in `block in call_processors'
  sprockets (3.1.0) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `reverse_each'
  sprockets (3.1.0) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `call_processors'
  sprockets (3.1.0) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:86:in `load_asset_by_uri'
  sprockets (3.1.0) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:45:in `block in load'
  sprockets (3.1.0) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:156:in `fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'
  sprockets (3.1.0) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:38:in `load'
  sprockets (3.1.0) lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:20:in `block in initialize'
  sprockets (3.1.0) lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `yield'
  sprockets (3.1.0) lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `load'
  sprockets (3.1.0) lib/sprockets/bundle.rb:23:in `block in call'
  sprockets (3.1.0) lib/sprockets/utils.rb:183:in `dfs'
  sprockets (3.1.0) lib/sprockets/bundle.rb:24:in `call'
  sprockets (3.1.0) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:75:in `call_processor'
  sprockets (3.1.0) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:57:in `block in call_processors'
  sprockets (3.1.0) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `reverse_each'
  sprockets (3.1.0) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `call_processors'
  sprockets (3.1.0) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:86:in `load_asset_by_uri'
  sprockets (3.1.0) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:45:in `block in load'
  sprockets (3.1.0) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:156:in `fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'
  sprockets (3.1.0) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:38:in `load'
  sprockets (3.1.0) lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:20:in `block in initialize'
  sprockets (3.1.0) lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `yield'
  sprockets (3.1.0) lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `load'
  sprockets (3.1.0) lib/sprockets/base.rb:63:in `find_asset'
  sprockets (3.1.0) lib/sprockets/environment.rb:30:in `find_asset'
  sprockets (3.1.0) lib/sprockets/base.rb:89:in `[]'
  sprockets-rails (2.3.1) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:243:in `lookup_asset_for_path'
  sprockets-rails (2.3.1) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:203:in `check_errors_for'
  sprockets-rails (2.3.1) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:172:in `block in stylesheet_link_tag'
  sprockets-rails (2.3.1) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:171:in `map'
  sprockets-rails (2.3.1) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:171:in `stylesheet_link_tag'
  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:9:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___3221601988042554075_70183562561420'
  actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
  actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/template.rb:333:in `instrument'
  actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
  actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:66:in `render_with_layout'
  actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:52:in `render_template'
  actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:14:in `render'
  actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:42:in `render_template'
  actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:23:in `render'
  actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:100:in `_render_template'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:217:in `_render_template'
  actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:83:in `render_to_body'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:32:in `render_to_body'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:37:in `render_to_body'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:25:in `render'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in `block (2 levels) in render'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `block in ms'
  /home/kaspar/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/benchmark.rb:303:in `realtime'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `ms'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in `block in render'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:84:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
  activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:25:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `render'
  app/controllers/application_controller.rb:35:in `intercept_html_requests'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:427:in `block in make_lambda'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:163:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:163:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:151:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:151:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:234:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:234:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `_run_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:734:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
  activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:137:in `process'
  actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:236:in `block in action'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:42:in `serve'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `each'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:802:in `call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
  rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in `call'
  rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
  rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in `call'
  rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
  rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:647:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/migration.rb:378:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `_run_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:734:in `_run_call_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
  better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:84:in `protected_app_call'
  better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:79:in `better_errors_call'
  better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:57:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  quiet_assets (1.1.0) lib/quiet_assets.rb:27:in `call_with_quiet_assets'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
  rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:113:in `call'
  rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
  railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
  railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/application.rb:164:in `call'
  passenger (5.0.7) lib/phusion_passenger/rack/thread_handler_extension.rb:89:in `process_request'
  passenger (5.0.7) lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:155:in `accept_and_process_next_request'
  passenger (5.0.7) lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:110:in `main_loop'
  passenger (5.0.7) lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler.rb:414:in `block (3 levels) in start_threads'
  passenger (5.0.7) lib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb:111:in `block in create_thread_and_abort_on_exception'
```

GEMfile:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

# Environment versions. These versions will be used for main development
# Make sure your own environment contains the same versions of Ruby and Ruby on Rails
ruby '2.2.0'
gem 'rails', '4.2.0'

# Gems for assets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0.3'
gem 'coffee-rails'
gem 'sprockets'

# Database gems
gem 'pg'
gem 'schema_plus'
gem 'redis'

# Rails server
gem 'passenger'

# Common gems
gem 'quiet_assets'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.2.11'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.1', group: :doc
gem 'devise'
gem 'paperclip'
gem 'active_model_serializers', '~> 0.10.0.rc2'
#gem 'active_model_serializers', '~> 0.9.3'
#gem 'active_model_serializers', '~> 0.8.3'
#gem 'active_model_serializers', github: 'rails-api/active_model_serializers'

group :development do
    gem 'better_errors'
    gem 'binding_of_caller', :platforms=>[:mri_21]
    gem 'rails_layout'
end

group :production do
    gem 'rails_12factor'
end

# Included web assets required by the project
source 'https://rails-assets.org' do
    gem 'rails-assets-bootstrap', '~> 3.3.5'
    gem 'rails-assets-purecss', '~> 0.6.0'
    gem 'rails-assets-angular', '~> 1.4.1'
    gem 'rails-assets-angular-route', '~> 1.4.1'
    gem 'rails-assets-angular-resource', '~> 1.4.1'
end
```

Comment: Can you link to the gem, it looks like there are several.

Comment: https://github.com/yahoo/pure    The gem fetches it for there. Gem name is rails-assets-purecss

Comment: In your Gemfile you've added the source block?  `source 'https://rails-assets.org' do` etc. and bundled?

Comment: Updated answer with gemfile.